# Fody-PropertyChanged raising on Dependent Property Change

Tags: c#, mvvm, fody, fody-propertychanged

I have a `ProjectModel` and a `ProjectViewModel` class; my Model handles direct manipulation of a project, while the view model is providing the "view friendly" properties and commands

However, in my ViewModel I'm exposing the read-only project contract for view binding

```
private ProjectModel Model { get; set; } 

public IProject Project
{
    get
    {
        return Model.Project;
    }
}
```

So here, the property `Model` doesn't change, but the property `Model.Project` will change, and so `Model` will raise its PropertyChanged event when it does

Now, I know [Fody-PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) has the ability to detect if a property is dependent on another property (in the same class) and raise the change event if the other changes.

I was wondering whether it is possible for [Fody-PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to raise `PropertyChanged("Project")` when the `Model` object raises its changed notifier.

I could do it manually, of course; but I'd prefer to stick with [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody). Is this a bad idea? Alternatively, is this a bad MVVM practice to begin with?

Comment: what value do you get by wrapping Model? Why not just bind directly to Model.Project

Comment: @Simon The value one gets is not quite evident by this particular example as it’s simplified (and rightfully so). Consider a case where the getter performs some logical curation on `Model.Project` before returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Fody-PropertyChanged does not currently support detecting wrapped properties in the way you describe.